# Logstash dissect filter is mapping to undefined type

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, logstash, kibana, filebeat

I am using Filebeat to send a log to Logstash, then to Elasticsearch and to Kibana.
Because each line of the log contains values delimited by '###', I use the 'dissect' filter to split up a single message block into different fields. My filter configuration:

```
dissect {
  mapping => {
    "message" => "%{date} %{time}###%{mode}###%{spec}###%{userid}### ..."
  }
  remove_field => [ "message" ]
}
```

So i dissect and remove the original message object. It works but it maps it to keywords of type 'undefined'
As shown in the screenshot below, it puts a '?' next to the field in Kibana.

[Kibana screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSXjD.png)

How can I make sure that it dissects to type 'string' or 'text'? Right now it is impossible to visualize this data, because it does not work with 'undefined' types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my own problem by replacing Filebeat as log feeder by using a tcp connection as log feeder.